# Installing Qt Components for Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am able to compile the source of qt-components just fine using the following steps:

1. Downloaded the tar.gz from http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/trees/master
2. Unpacked the components
3. Added path variable value to the environment variables for mingw and qmake
4. Ran the following command: qmake && make install

I can see that the above command exits successfully and copies the qml files and a few other folders to `C:\Qt_2.8.0\Qt4.8.4\imports\QtDesktop`

I then open up qtcreator and inside of my qml file, I type `import QtDesktop 0.1`, but it returns an error of `module "QtDesktop" is not installed`. If I hover over the QtDesktop import statement, it reads `Library at C:\Qt_2.8.0\Qt4.8.4\imports\QtDesktop - Dumped plugins succesfully`.

...so what I am doing wrong here?
Please note that I am constricted in using Qt4

Comment: Get Qt5, those are part of the standard package.

Comment: It seems like you need to build Qt from the source code. I would rather get the distributive from http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.0/ as it is offered on Qt Project site. Mind that you need to *configure* the Qt build http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html https://community.freescale.com/thread/282875 I have only done building Qt 5 with QML for tweaking certain OpenGL options but the principle the same.